# How to add certificate pinning to mqtt for iOS application?

Tags: ios, mqtt, mosquitto

I am using Moscapsule which is using mosquitto underneath, to perform mqtt connections for my iOS app. I know there are server and client certs that we can set as options.

Does setting these cause certificate pinning?

Is there a way to get the server cert and perform certificate validation?

Comment: did you get a solution for this? I also need to implement certificate pinning for mqtt iOS.

Comment: MQTT Client supports cert pinning.  https://github.com/novastone-media/MQTT-Client-Framework/pull/34   -- If the underlying mosquitto doesn't support cert pinning then adding it to the Moscapsule wrapper is not trivial